# Hypothesis testing for non-independent data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Researchers collected the following data concerning comparability of diagnoses of
schizophrenia obtained from primary-care physician report as compared with proxy
report (from spouses). Data was collected from 953 people. The researchers found
that schizophrenia was identified as present on 115 physician reports and 124 proxy
reports. Both physician and proxy informants identified 34 people as positive for
schizophrenia.

How do I compare the percentage of subjects identified as schizophrenic by the two reports? And how do I test if there is a significant agreement between the two reports. Can someone please help me on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Well, you could assume that the physician reports were normative, analyze the distribution that would yield, and see whether the proxy results were probable.

Comment: @lulu, what do you mean by normative?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the question.  What does the $953$ have to do with anything?  And what is the difference between "schizophrenia identified as present" and "positive for schizophrenia"?

Comment: I was assuming (probably incorrectly) that you had two samples, sample $A$ had $115$ members and $34$ positives, sample $B$ had $124$ members and also had $34$ positives.  But in that case I am ignoring the $953$ entirely.

Comment: @lulu, 953 is the grand total number of people sampled. The intersection between the physician report and the proxy report is 34. Meaning 34 were sampled from physician and proxy report.

Comment: This isn't clear at all.  Do we have both physician reports and proxy reports on all $953$?

Comment: @lulu, yes! The total (953) is inclusive of 34.

Comment: Ok.  I suggest editing your post...I don't think anyone is likely to find this interpretation.

Comment: To your question, there appear to be lots of patients who only score positive on one of the two reports, so the two methods are in conflict.  Not sure how much more can be said...are you assuming that one set of reports is always accurate?

Comment: What hypothesis is it you want to test?

Comment: @I am not sure. I was thinking of binomial proportion test for the first part and kappa statistic for the second part? But I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I wasn't asking what test you were using, I was asking what the hypothesis was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85994/discussion-between-lady-and-lulu).

Answer (score 0):

**Clue,** to get you started: My interpretation of your question is that
you need to finish filling in the frequencies in the following $2 \times 2$ table. (This can be done by simple arithmetic from the counts provided.)
Then use the completed table to do a chi-squared test of independence.

```
                   Physician
                ---------------
                Yes          No         Total 
---------------------------------------------
       Yes       34                      124
Spouse
       No
--------------------------------------------
       Total    115                      953
```

**Addendum,** Results from Minitab statistical software are shown below. Do you know how to find
`Expected counts`, `Contributions`, and `Pearson chi-sq statistic`?
Null hypothesis that Physicians and Spouses make judgments
about schizophrenia in independent ways is rejected. That is,
both physicians and spouses must be looking at some of the same
symptoms. Briefly put, under independence, we would 'expect' only
about 15 agreements on 'Yes', but we observe 34 agreements (more than twice as
many as expected).

```
Chi-Square Test for Association: Spouse, Worksheet columns 

Rows: Spouse   Columns: Worksheet columns

       PhyYes  PhyNo  All

Yes        34     90  124
         15.0  109.0
       24.219  3.324

No         81    748  829
        100.0  729.0
        3.623  0.497

All       115    838  953

Cell Contents:      Count
                    Expected count
                    Contribution to Chi-square

Pearson Chi-Square = 31.662, DF = 1, P-Value = 0.000
```

*Note;* Formally, a standard test comparing the physicians' estimate $115/953$ with
the spouses' estimate $124/953$ is shown below. It shows no significant
difference. However, this is supposed to be a comparison of two *independent*
proportions, which we do not seem to have here.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X    N  Sample p
1       124  935  0.132620
2       115  935  0.122995

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.00962567
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0206363, 0.0398876)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 0.62  P-Value = 0.533
```